# in cursor.updateRow(row) RuntimeError: Object invalid or no longer set

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5, runtimeerror, idle

I'm running an arcpy code in IDLE that update a field in shapefile. After updating it get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/10/Desktop/test.py", line 21, in cursor.updateRow(row_st) RuntimeError: Object invalid or no longer set.

And, here is the code:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"D:\Phd-Files\dataset.mdb"
env.overwriteOutput = True

fields_Street=["OBJECTID","SHAPE@","t_light_de", "st_dense", "bikeLn_den", "Buff_area", "len"]

cursor= arcpy.UpdateCursor("Boston_Street_Buff_10_Joint", fields_Street)
for row_st in cursor:
    geom = row_st.getValue('Shape')
    # calculate street density 
    _area_buff=0
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(geom, "geom_buff", "10 Meters")
    cursor_buff= arcpy.SearchCursor("geom_buff", ["ORIG_FID", "Shape_Area"])
    for row_buff in cursor_buff:
        _area_buff=_area_buff+ row_buff.getValue('Shape_Area')
        row_st.setValue ('st_dense' , row_st.getValue('Buff_area')/_area_buff)
    del cursor_buff, row_buff
    print ('street_ObjectID={0}, bike_lane density= {1}'.format(row_st.getValue('OBJECTID'), row_st.getValue('st_dense')))
    cursor.updateRow(row_st)
    arcpy.Delete_management("geom_buff")
```

Comment: Just a comment, I don't believe you need to delete the cursor using the `del` statement as you are using the cursors within a `with` statement which is supposed to guarantee release of resources, well that is my understanding

Comment: It seems as the `updateRow()` method is fed with an invalid object. Try to examine the `row_st` before you are trying to update the row. Also, I would strongly suggest rewriting the code where you work with `area_buff` and `row_buff`. I've been trying to follow the code but all those index-based access with `[-1]` and `[-4]` makes it so difficult. `namedtuple` would be handy here.

Comment: Totally agree with @AlexTereshenkov your use of  index-based access of the row object is _Very_ difficult to follow.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov your right. code is modified.

Comment: You should be getting an indentation error on line 11 (geom = row_st.getValue('Shape')). Once you've copied your code over correctly, and we can see what you're running, we might be able to help.

Comment: @Tom code is edited.

Comment: Have you tested it since editing the code? It looks like it should work. Is the error the same? BTW, you can dedent the `row_st.setValue` line and the result should be the same, but it will run a little faster.

Comment: @Tom yes I tested and it give the same error.

Comment: First, `arcpy.UpdateCursor` and `arcpy.SearchCursor` are deprecated in favor of the "data access" versions, `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` and `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`.  I would recommend using those instead.  Secondly, geometry objects have a geom.buffer() method which would allow you to avoid running the Buffer_analysis inside of the loop and therefore avoid having a nested search cursor.  They also have an area attribute.

Comment: what row/field are you trying to update?

Answer (score 1):

I use shp file instead of mdb and it dosent get error. As it works on shp, i have to update Shape_Area at the buffer. i use `expression1 = "{0}".format("!SHAPE.area@SQUERMETERS!")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("geom_buff.shp", "Shape_Area", expression1, "PYTHON")` and that works for me.